# Getting MSFT_Partition from MSFT_Disk using Associators

Tags: c#, winapi, wmi

I am trying to get a list of `MSFT_Partitions` from a `MSFT_Disk` object and loop over them.
This is the code I have been using so far but it always outputs an `System.Management.ManagementException: 'Invalid query '` exception.

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```cs
public static void GetDiskInfo() {
    var rawDiskInfos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Storage", "SELECT * FROM MSFT_Disk");
    foreach(var rawDiskInfo in rawDiskInfos.Get()) {
        Console.WriteLine(rawDiskInfo["FriendlyName"]);
        GetPartitionInfo(rawDiskInfo["ObjectId"]);
    }
}

public static void GetPartitionInfo(object objectId) {
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Storage");

    var query = new ObjectQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {MSFT_Disk.ObjectId=\"" + objectId + "\"} WHERE AssocClass = MSFT_DiskToPartition");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

    foreach(var partiton in queryCollection) {
        Console.WriteLine(partiton["Guid"]);
    }
}
```

I already tried a lot of solutions I found online and all of them resulted in the same exception.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most queries you'll find on the internet don't do it, but in the general case, you must escape raw strings you pass to WQL queries (in your case `objectId` contains special characters), using the [backslash character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/where-clause), with a method like this:

```
public static string EscapeWql(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
        return null;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
    foreach (var c in text)
    {
        if (c == '\\' || c == '\'' || c == '"')
        {
            sb.Append('\\');
        }
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

So your method should now look like this:

```
public static void GetPartitionInfo(object objectId)
{
    var scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage");
    var query = new ObjectQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {MSFT_Disk.ObjectId=\"" + EscapeWql((string)objectId) + "\"} WHERE AssocClass = MSFT_DiskToPartition");
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
    {
        using (var queryCollection = searcher.Get())
        {
            foreach (var partition in queryCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(partition["Guid"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: don't forget using statements on `IDisposable` classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works perfectly! What is the benefit of using the IDisposable classes? Is it improving performance?

Comment: No, it releases (unmanaged) resources held by .NET classes, so when you're finished with a disposable instance, it's better to dispose it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: Wow that was a fast answer. Thank you for all your help!